# Logstash data showing up as "message" field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to send some raw data to elasticsearch through logstash. I am trying to do this through the udp plugin but for now I dont think this is relevant.

Basically, I with to send key/value pairs, and I wish for this to show up as:

```
{
    "key_1": "value_1"
    ....
}
```

instead of:

```
{
    "message": "{\"key1\": \"value1\"}"
}
```

Is there any way for logstash to somehow "decode" the message as json and insert them as top level keys?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your Logstash config, you probably simply need to use the `json` codec in your input instead of the `plain` one.

Comment: You are correct, I just needed to use the json codec and provide some actually valid json. Im an eejit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use a "json" codec on the input like so:

```
input {
    udp {
            port => 3425
            codec => "json"
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val) for pointing this out